# google maps markerInfowindow delegate not calling ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, infowindow, marker

I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS app. I need to customize markerinfowindow. I add

1) `@interface MapsViewController : UIViewController GMSMapViewDelegate`

2)   `mapView_.delegate = self;` in viewdidload and

3)

```
 - (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
            UIView *InfoWindow = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 200)];
            UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
             nameLabel.text = @"hi";
             [InfoWindow addSubview:nameLabel];

    return InfoWindow;
}
```

but control is not comming in  markerInfoWindow.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem - markerInfoWindow wouldn't get called even after setting the delegate.
Ended up doing this:

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView*)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker*)marker
{
  [mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
  return YES;
}
```

setSelectedMarker will force a call on markerInfoWindow.

Comment: i know this as i did in obj c but forgot in swift. thanks to remeber this +1

Comment: I upvoted as I got the solution using your answer.Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

To Use `markerInfoWindow` method for custom Callout, you also need to set its anchor using `infoWindowAnchor` property.

When you create your marker set the anchor:

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = MARKER_POSITION;
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44f, 0.45f);
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomMarkerImageName"];
```

then create the delegate method.

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
  InfoWindow *view =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
  view.name.text = @"Place Name";
  view.description.text = @"Place description";
  view.phone.text = @"123 456 789";
  view.placeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customPlaceImage"];
  view.placeImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-.08);
  return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok it is solve i add 
mapView_.delegate = self;
before marker making thanks